# Oracle SQL developer connect issue

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Unable to connect to the oracle database using SQL DEVELOPER. I notice the below error while trying to connect to the DB.

Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01882: timezone region not found

SQL Developer version: 20.2.0.175.1842
Oracle Version: 11.2.0.4

[image]

Comment: HI, i tried this approach and when I modify the suggested changes and try to open the sqldeveloper exe file, it throws a pop up saying the file is corrupted

Comment: Which file is it saying? And exactly what did you try?

Comment: How can I edit ojdbc.jar in the mac machine? Earlier, I tried changing this(ojdbc8 jar) using some third-party software.

Comment: Your link tells me to set -Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false in the odbc8.jar file. How can we do this in Mac machine?

Comment: Don't touch the jar file, just add that line to the sqldeveloper.conf file

Comment: it is working, much thanks!

Comment: Best news of the day, so far!!